# Build Lowest Number by Removing n digits from a given number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl

It takes as input a number(string) and then the task is to remove n numbers to give a resulting lowest possible number, but you have to take care of the order, that is the constraint. You cannot change the order of the original numbers.

I wanted it to work in O(n), so I did this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#lowestNS.pl
#Date: 2016-06-28

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

(@ARGV == 2) or die "2 args needed";
my $num = $ARGV[0];
my $d = $ARGV[1];
my @arr;

int($num) > 0 or die "Enter positive number";

print "Number in: $num\nDel: $d\n";

if(int($num) == 0) {
    print "Result: 0\n";
    exit;
}
else {
    my $str = $num;
    @arr = split(//, $str); #/Split on each number
    #Split and multiply by reverse index, to give precedence to the order of numbers
    for(my $i = 0; $i < @arr; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] *= (@arr - $i);
    }
}

print "arr: " . join(',' , @arr) . "\n";

for (my $j = 0; $j < $d; $j++) {
    my $max = $arr[0];
    my $m_index = -1;

    #replace nth maximum with -1

    for (my $i = 0; $i < @arr; $i++) {
        if($max <= $arr[$i]) {
            $max = $arr[$i];
            $m_index = $i;
        }
    }
    $arr[$m_index] = -1;
}


#return all numbers with value other than -1

my $result = "";

for (my $i = 0; $i < @arr; $i++) {
    if($arr[$i] != -1){
        $result = $result . "" . $arr[$i]/(@arr - $i);
    }
}

print "Result: $result\n";
```

It works in all cases, except, cases like: 
`Number = 765028321`
`Delete = 5` 
The problem is the removal of 7650`2`8321 when it should have removed the 765028`3`21.
because 2*5 > 3*3.

Comment: Is this casual programming / a puzzle?

Comment: should it not remove 8 so that the resulting number is even lesser than when you removed 3?

Comment: @Borodin, It is a puzzle.
@Tejash, Actually the result should be: `0221`, but my program outputs `0321`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. In the given example, there are `9 digits` in input number and you have to remove `5` of them? In that case, remove `76583`, so resulting number will be `0221` which is lowest. Or am I missing something?

Comment: And, can you mention the constraints, like length of input (number) string, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the algorithm is straightforward:

Suppose, N is the number of digits to delete;
1. Find the first smallest digit in the first N digits, delete digits to the left of it, decrease N by the number of digits deleted.
2. if N>0 take the digits to the right and repeat the steps above.
Of course, we need to check for marginal cases, and to ensure the final number does not start with 0.
Here is the code draft:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($number, $del)=@ARGV;
my @num = $number=~m{.}g;
my $curpos=0;
my @finalnum;
for(;;) {
  last if $del <=0 || $curpos+$del>=@num;
  my $minpos=$curpos;
  for (my $i=$curpos;$i<$curpos+$del+1 && $i < @num;$i++) {
    if ($num[$i]<$num[$minpos] && !($curpos==0 && $num[$i]==0)) {
      $minpos=$i;
    }
  }
  push @finalnum, $num[$minpos];
  $del-=($minpos-$curpos);
  $curpos=$minpos+1;
}
push @finalnum, @num[$curpos+$del..$#num] if $curpos+$del < @num;
print join '', @finalnum;
```

Comment: I have thought of another possible solution now that does this:
Repeat d times(number of digits to delete):
1. Start traversing the array and find a pair of `int`s such that the first is greater than the other and remove it.
2. If not keep traversing and remove the last element you reach.
3. Repeat from step 1 on the newly formed number.

Comment: I think it would work, and the code would be shorter.

Comment: Yeah I hope. Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score -2):

A possible solution can be:

1. Create an array having count of all digits, eg. in your case, this array will look like: `1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,0`
2. Then, in a greedy manner, remove all `big` digits, as many as can be done. So, you remove 9s, but since its count is 0, you still need to remove 5 digits. Remove 8s, so you still need to remove 4 digits and so on.
3. This case is kind of trivial, so you will be left with `2 2's, 1 1's and 1 0's`. In there were, say `3 4's` also in the number, you will then need to remove 1 4. So, you will remove the leftmost of partial removals required.

Its a greedy approach, and works in O(n).